# Deleting user function SQL query doesn't send anything (PHP)

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

So basically, I've got a function in PHP that deletes an user from the same row when a form is submit, the form does submit, the function does do it's thing, but the user is not deleted.

```
 $html = '';
    $html .= '<table><form method="post" action="index.php?controller=user&action=delUser">';
    foreach( $auser as $user) {
        $html .= '<tr><td><input type="hidden" value="'.$user['id'].'"><input type="submit" name="delUserSubmit" value=""> '.$user["id"].' '.$user["voornaam"].' '.$user["tv"].' '.$user["achternaam"].'</td></tr>';
    }
    $html .= '</form></table>';

    return $html;
}
```

So in this form, it sends the id through a hidden input field which carries the user id

```
public function delUser()
{
    if(isset($_POST['delUserSubmit'])) {
        $sql = "DELETE FROM user WHERE id = ".$_POST['id'];
        $this->oDb->insUpdDelQuery($sql);
        unset($_POST);
        header("Location: index.php?controller=user&action=show");
    }
}
```

When it reaches the above function, it goes through the isset $_POST etc. Since when everytime I do submit the form, I go to the page at which the header is pointing.

But when it reaches the user page, the user is still there.
Now the problem could either be:

1. I don't actually send the id
2. I do send the id, but the $sql doesn't get the id somehow? the `delUser()` function is empty whereas something like `show($id=null)` shows all the users.
3. the `delUser()` needs something like `$_POST['id']`, but that would give unexpected characters in my editor.

Can't fix this, anybody able to help?

Comment: just so you know, this is leaving you wide open to SQL injection attacks by not using prepared statements

Comment: @jtylerm thanks, but this is not intended for public use, I'm a first year student and this is basically my homework

Comment: Do you see the correct `id` when you `var_dump($_POST['id']);` on the function delUser()?

Comment: You are missing the "name" attribute in this part of the HTML... `<input type="hidden" value="'.$user['id'].'">`. It should be `<input name="id" type="hidden" value="'.$user['id'].'">`

Comment: @BA_Webimax Thanks! That solved it.

Comment: @ClaudioBusatto Hey, it was solved, but when I removed the correct answer and tried your method to see if it was the correct id I saw that there was no $id at all, this will help in the future, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

POST values are submitted using the `name` attribute on the `input` field.

Change your HTML input to

```html
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$user['id'].'">
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks, this solved it, will mark as solved when the timer ends.

Comment: I am glad that helped you, succes in your studies!

Answer (score 0):

You have not set anything in the from to $_POST['id']. The name of the posted element is taken from the *name* in the html form. The input tag that has the value of id needs to have the the name set to id:

```
<input type="hidden" value="'.$user['id'].'" name="id">
```